# Can we rename the [go] tag to something else?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

It's clear that many new users don't know how to use tags. They try to tag [pokemon-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-go) writing `pokemon (space) go` and we get a lot of questions tagged [pokemon-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-series) and [go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go).

Due to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13913/how-to-unmark-groups-as-dead-in-kgs-go) we have a [go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go) tag (which techically is a boardgame, not a videogame), so can we just edit its name in order to avoid that annoying habit?

At least somebody added `DO NOT USE FOR POKEMON GO` in [pokemon-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-series) excerpt, but I don't see many benefits.

Comment: I don't think this is particularly a bad idea. Is a tag really needed when only 1 question uses it? Tags are meant to help find similar questions, help with filtering, etc. Removing [tag:go] sounds like it would save many edits to new questions. But, I'm a noob here and I don't know the general tagging culture here.

Comment: @TimMalone -  We tag with the specific game wherever possible, even if there's only one question about it. We have very few non-game/console specific tags, like [terminology], [achievements] etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag [go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go) has been replaced with [kgs-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kgs-go), and [go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go) has been synonymised with [pokemon-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-go) (for the time being at least, to ease moderation effort).

[kgs-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kgs-go) is a more suitable tag for that one question, as it is about functionality to do with the [KGS Go platform](https://www.gokgs.com/) not the board game 'Go', meaning it's still on-topic for us.

Answer (score 3):

We should remove the tag completely.

There is currently only one question using the tag, and it is about a feature of the specific application used for it. It's also 5 years old. This should be tagged to refer to KGS.

Any questions about Go strategy are off-topic here and belong in [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go).

Comment: I agree, [kgs] tag should be more suitable.