# The game Go is replaced by a synonym for PokemonGo

Tags: support, meta

I am an enthusiastic player of the board game called Go ([Wikipedia on Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game))), as it's called in Japan and "the West".  (It's known as "Baduk" in Korea, and "Weiqi" in China.)  Though originally a board game, Go is now played widely over the internet, similar to Chess.  And there recently was a media interest in Go when it became the last complete-knowledge game where computers defeated high-level professionals ([Google DeepMind / AlphaGo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlphaGo_versus_Lee_Sedol)).

There used to be a tag for Go on gaming.SE.  It is now replaced with a synonym for PokemonGo.

I understand that PokemonGo has achieved more popularity in a year than Go has achieved in 2000 years.  (I expect that Go will still be played 2000 years in the future, while I suspect PokemonGo may be, by then, long forgotten.)  Still, it bothers me that Go seems to have been obliterated here.  I find no trace of the (small handful of) questions that were here.

I participate here sporadically, or I would have voiced my concern sooner.  Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'Go' is a board game not a video game and therefore generic 'Go' strategy and gameplay questions are off-topic here. If you are looking for questions about the rules & strategies for Go, our sister site [Board and Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go) handles this.

If your question is specifically about a video game rendition of Go i.e. features specific to that game version, you can ask it here. There was *one* question tagged 'Go' on Arqade, and it is now tagged [kgs-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kgs-go) (standing for the online 'Go' platform of the same name).

As for why 'Go' is synonymised with Pokemon Go, see [this discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11882/28182) - Synonyms exist to redirect common mistags or misspellings - Pokemon Go questions were being tagged 'Pokemon' <space> 'Go', requiring a lot of community effort to fix the tagging.